# How do I scrape the about section of a Facebook page?

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

How  do I scrape pages from the [Facebook About section](https://www.facebook.com/pg/*/about). Can I use [Facebook Graph API](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=facebook%20graph%20api&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB766GB766&oq=facebook%20graph&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.6378j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or should I use a Python web-scraping library like [Scrappy](https://scrapy.org/) of [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)?

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. you have to use the graph api.

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook Graph API is for ["apps to read and write to the Facebook social graph"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) so you cannot use it in this case. Instead, you should use a Python scraping-libary like [beautifulsoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io).

An example of scraping the Facebook About Page for the organizations mission statement might look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.facebook.com/pg/officialstackoverflow/about/?ref=page_internal")
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html")
mission_statement = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': '_3-8w'})
print(mission_statement.text)
> To make the internet a better place and be the best site to find expert answers to your programming questions.
```